# Rolled up and down winform when

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Newbie in C# here, I want to make a custom win form, which behaves like this:

- when I double click first time [from normal size] it rolls up
- win form height changed to about 20
- when I double click second time it will roll down back to original height

This is my version, but I couldn't seen how it work, only rolled up only worked, but when I double click second time , it didn't rolled down.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication15
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                
        }

        bool thisRolled = false;

        public static void resiseMe(Form frm, int newHeight, bool maximIt)
        {
            if (newHeight > 27)
            {
                bool loopEnd = false;

                if (maximIt == false)
                {
                    while (loopEnd == false && frm.Height >= newHeight)
                    {
                        // ticks2 = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
                        int thisHeight = frm.Height--;

                        Application.DoEvents();
                        if (thisHeight == newHeight)
                        {
                            loopEnd = true;
                        }
                        //Thread.Sleep(2);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    while (loopEnd == false && frm.Height <= newHeight)
                    {
                        int thisHeight = frm.Height++;
                        if (thisHeight == newHeight)
                        {
                            loopEnd = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
        {                
            if (thisRolled == true)
            {
                resiseMe(this, 28, false);
            }
            else
            {
                resiseMe(this, 320, true);
            }

            base.OnDoubleClick(e);
        }

        protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Height <= 50)
            {
                thisRolled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                thisRolled = false;
            }

            base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Please someone help/suggest me how to make it work.

Comment: Gah!! Application.DoEvents means you are doing something *horribly* wrong. To get it working, try putting that in your "expand" loop. Then learn how to do animations the right way.

Comment: Sorry man, im still newbie , just starting to walk, aahh...btw Thanks for pointing it where s the correct way.

@RSSM & yazam : thanks, Ill try it out both your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try This it might help

```
    public static void resiseMe(Form frm, int newHeight)
    {
        new Task(() =>
        {
            int pause = 100;

            int steps = 5;
            int diff = newHeight - frm.Height;

            int adjust = diff / steps;

            for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
            {
                frm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(()=>{
                    frm.Height += adjust;
                    frm.Refresh();

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(pause);
                }));
            }
        }).Start();
    }

    protected override void OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
    {                
        if (thisRolled)
        {
            resiseMe(this, this.Height - 50);
        }
        else
        {
            resiseMe(this, this.Height + 50);
        }

        thisRolled = !thisRolled; // flip the thisRolled Value

        base.OnDoubleClick(e);
    }
```

if you want to speed up the animation decrease the `pause` variable.

Answer (score 0):

thisRolled is always false.

Add thisRolled = true; in your 2nd while loop of resiseMe

Also your resiseMe is currently a static method. So you either need to declare thisRolled as static  (static bool thisRolled =  false;)  or remove the static from public static void resiseMe